# android prevent showing keyboard on dialog.show

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is there a way to prevent the keyboard appear automatically when dialog is showing up.

here is my code for my dialog box

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.shopping_cart_confirm_dialog);
                    TextView txtConfirmEmail = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtConfirmEmail);
                    ...
                    dialog.show();
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) you should be able to hide the keyboard.

Check [hideSoftInputFromWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#hideSoftInputFromWindow%28android.os.IBinder,%20int%29). It accepts a windowtoken returned by

```
View.getWindowToken()


InputMethodManager mgr=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(dialog.getWindow().getWindowToken(), 0);
```